# Xcode Storyboard: cornerRadius of a Label (macOS)

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

I want to give a label (background color is red) a cornerRadius of 20.

I've tried this code:

```swift
import Cocoa
import QuartzCore

class ViewController: NSViewController {



    @IBOutlet var blueback: NSTextField!





    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        blueback.layer.masksToBounds = true
        blueback.layer.cornerRadius = 50



    }

    override var representedObject: Any? {
        didSet {
        // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }


}
```

However, I get the errors: 
`Value of optional type 'CALayer?' must be unwrapped to refer to member 'masksToBounds' of wrapped base type 'CALayer'` on each line which starts with `blueback`

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do optional chaining to avoid the `error`. Also, You need to set the `blueback`'s `wantsLayer` property to `true`.

```swift
blueback.wantsLayer = true
blueback.layer?.masksToBounds = true
blueback.layer?.cornerRadius = 50
```